# Has own property and test for actual name

Tags: jquery, json

I was wondering how to test if a json file has an object present and if so how to test if the actual name/string equals to a specific name. So if an object is present then test if that object equals the name "Maten" and if so then do the next $.each...

What I mean:

JSON

```
...
"options": {

    "95217": {
    "id": 95217,
    "title": "kleur",
    "values": {.....}

},
    "95219": {
    "id": 95219,
    "title": "Maat",
    "values":  {.....}
}, etc...
```

Jquery

```
     $.getJSON('url?format=json', function(data){
          var options = [];
          $.each(data.product.options, function(index, option){

// Here I want to test if object "title" equals maten and if so do the next $.each ////

         if(option.hasOwnProperty('title')){


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

              $.each(option.values, function (index, value) {
                options.push('<li>'+value.title+'</li>');
              });

            }
          });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `in` operator and logical AND

```
if ( 'title' in option && option.title === 'maten'){ ....
```

Comment: Is `'title' in option` necessary? If `option` has no `title` property, then `option.title` will be `undefined`, and `undefined !== 'maten'`. It would make sense checking `option.hasOwnProperty('title')` to be sure that property is an own one, though.

Comment: @Oriol - true, `option.title` is fine as well, I just like the `in` operator. However I don't see the need for `hasOwnProperty` on an object coming from JSON that clearly has no prototyped properties

Comment: @adeneo: Thx for a new way to accomplish this!